# searching for min(y) with the corresponding x (x and y are arrays)

Tags: python, python-3.x

`

> import numpy as np
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> x = np.array([3900.06,3900.16,3900.26])
>
> y = np.array([0.311254,0.588623,0.724301])
>
> if min(y):
>
> print(x[min(y)])`

maybe someone can help me with the following problem:
I'm searching for the x point where the point y is at minimum.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKylE.png)

Thanks, for any kind of help :)

Comment: Pleas post actual code. not an image of code, so people can copy, test and reproduce it easily.

Comment: _Maybe_ someone _can_ help you, but first please post the data as text and not as an image.

Comment: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


x = np.array([3900.06,3900.16,3900.26])
y = np.array([0.311254,0.588623,0.724301])

if min(y): 
    print(x[min(y)])

Comment: x[np.argmin(y)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing whether or not y has a min (not sure if this is a requirement for the application without more source), using [`np.argmin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([3900.06, 3900.16, 3900.26])
y = np.array([0.311254, 0.588623, 0.724301])

print(x[np.argmin(y)])
```